# How can I connect Google Classroom to Bubble.io using Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-classroom, bubble.io

I am trying to use the Google Classroom API to log into a Bubble.io application that I have made using the api connector. I have the following setup however I am getting an error when I try to log in:

[image: API connector setup]

This is the result after I try logging in:

[image: Login result error]

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Have created OAuth2 credentials for the application you will use to call the Classroom API in your GCP project at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes, I have, just took it off in order to take pictures and post on here.

Comment: Have you authorized the domain in your consent screen at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/? And do your credentials's redirect url match the one given by bubble.io ".../oauth_redirect"?